Difference between real element borders and gsap markers
I was using GSAP ScrollTrigger to make a vertical slider of images. The idea is that a hidden elements with id=scroller takes a certain height (I choose it to be 400 vh) while all the content is in fixed position, when you scroll down the #scroller element scrolltrigger moves the slider vertically, each time an element x of the slider enters a certain area the main background changes to the x background
I have a scroll trigger that animates the slider:
gsap.to('#slider',{
        scrollTrigger:{
            trigger: "#scroller",
            start: 0,
            scrub: 1,
            snap:"labelsDirectional"
        },
        y:-sliderH*6-80,
    })

and another trigger that changes the background according to slider position
let elems=document.querySelectorAll('.slider-elem')
let heroBacks=document.querySelectorAll('.hero-back')
elems=Array.from(elems)
ScrollTrigger.batch(elems, {
    onLeave: (elements, triggers) => {
        gsap.to(heroBacks[heroBacks.length-elems.indexOf(elements[0])-1], { opacity: 0})
    },
    onEnterBack: (elements, triggers) => {
        x=gsap.to(heroBacks[heroBacks.length-elems.indexOf(elements[0])-1], { opacity: 1})
        console.log(x)
    },
    start:'top 60%',
    end:'bottom 10%',
    markers:true
});

When I scroll down everything works fine except that a difference occurs between slider elements real borders (top bottom) and the ones indicated in the markers



The solution is to add a scrollTrigger.refresh() to update start,end value and assign it to onEnter callback so it becomes:
let elems=document.querySelectorAll('.slider-elem')
elems=Array.from(elems)
ScrollTrigger.batch(elems, {
    onLeave: (elements, triggers) => {
        gsap.to(heroBacks[heroBacks.length-elems.indexOf(elements[0])-1], { opacity: 0})
    },
    onEnter:(elems,trigs)=>{
        for(trig of trigs){
            trig.refresh()
        }
    },
    onEnterBack: (elements, triggers) => {
        x=gsap.to(heroBacks[heroBacks.length-elems.indexOf(elements[0])-1], { opacity: 1})
    },
    start:'top 60%',
    end:'bottom 10%',
    markers:true
});

